# how to programmatically focus on dropdowns

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Using the Angular 2 Dropdowns, how can I programmatically set focus to it?
the examples show how to get the focus event, but not how to set focus.

thanks

Comment: Call `element.focus()`.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/#toc-focus

Comment: Just be careful! The tab key should already do this - and if you set focus on a dropdown when the user might be about to use up/down arrows to scroll the screen then you can get in trouble. If it's a shopping cart you'll quickly get emails : "I did not order 50 of these!"

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your dropdowns are select, for i don't know what a kendo dropdown is. Start by creatign a local variable :

```
<select #dropdown></select>
```

In your component, get that variable reference :

```
@ViewChild() dropdown: ElementRef;
```

Now, you can trigger the focus with

```
this.dropdown.nativeElement.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use one directive like this!

```
export class FocusDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: it actually should be this.el.nativeElement.focus();

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Kendo DropDownListComponent you can call the focus method following these steps:

**In the component typescript file:**

```
import { DropDownListComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
```

Reference the dropdown control using a viewchild:

```
@ViewChild("myDropdown") myDropdown: DropDownListComponent;
```

Implement ngAfterViewInit and call focus in the function (this will set the focus when the DOM is loaded):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myDropdown.focus();
}
```

**In your template file:**

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
  #myDropdown              
  [data]="data"
  [textField]="'value'"
  [valueField]="'key'">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```